# android device imei pass to another class

Tags: android

I want to pass android device id or imei number but when i pass from one class to another then application crash.
But it work fine when i am call with in same class plz help i am new to android.

```
package com.example.deviceid;


 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
 import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
 import android.widget.Toast;

public class GetId extends Activity {
String deviceId;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public String AndroidId(){
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager =   (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String imei=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    return imei;
  }

}
```

It is main class in which i am call imei number.

```
  package com.example.deviceid;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.os.Bundle;

  import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  public class ShowDeviceInfo extends Activity {
     GetId gi;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.main);
  gi = new GetId();
  String imei = gi.AndroidId();
  Toast.makeText(this, imei, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

XML file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.deviceid.ShowDeviceInfo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.deviceid.GetId"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
  </application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 </manifest>
```

Comment: why you need to go in another activity you can directly call it in first activity it self.

Comment: show your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.. May be you had not declared second activity there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first actiivty you have not set the content

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main); // missing this statement
}
```

You are not navigating to the second activity. You do not call AndroidId() in your first activity.

You can pass values between activities using intents.

In your first activity

```
   Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("imeid",imei);// key value
   startActivity(i);
```

In Second Actiivty

```
   Bundle extras= getIntent().getExtras();
   if(extras!=null)
   {
       String IMEI= extras.getString("imeid");// retrieve using key
   }
```

Edit:

Not sure why you want to pass the imei to another class. You can get the imei number in the mainactivity and use the same.

please read the actiivty lifecycle

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager =   (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String imei=telephonyManager.getDeviceId(); 
            Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("key",imei);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
}

  }
```

second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

SecondActivity

```
  public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null)
    {
        TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(extras.getString("key").toString());
    }
}
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
      <activity
        android:name="com.example.testintent.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

//ur only implementing getid mtd in getid class.so no need to extend activity.
//getid class

```
public class GetId{
String deviceId;
public String AndroidId(){
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager =   (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String imei=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    return imei;
  }
}
```

//main activity

```
public class ShowDeviceInfo extends Activity {
     GetId gi;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.main);
    gi = new GetId();
    String imei = gi.AndroidId();
   Toast.makeText(this, imei, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

//manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.deviceid.ShowDeviceInfo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```